# nodejs Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, foreach

guys i get this error in my nodejs application but i not understand what is wrong and what is problem with 'forEach'.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined,

```
var request = require('request');
var log4js = require('log4js');
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
var fs = require('fs');
var prices;
setInterval(function(){
    request('https://api.csgofast.com/price/all', function(error, response, body) {
        prices = JSON.parse(body);
        var newprice = JSON.parse('{"response":{"success":1,"current_time":1464567644,"items":{}}}');
prices.prices.forEach(function(item) {
                                newprice.response.items['migration_time_validation'] = JSON.stringify(database_params);
                                newprice.response.items[item.market_hash_name] = {
                                        "value": item.price

                                }
                        });
        fs.writeFileSync('C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/test/prices.txt', body);
        logger.trace('New prices loaded.');
    });
}, 3);
```

Comment: There is no `prices` item/key in the response of the API. That's why `prices.prices` is undefined.

Comment: Why are you parsing a string literal?

Comment: i try to convert prices from csgofast to model like a bitskins but yea json is different my bad .... thanks guys i will try another model :)

Answer (score 0):

`prices.prices` is undefined. You can however try to store the reponse/data in `prices.txt`

```
Array.from(prices).forEach(function(item){...};
```